# Creating and Launching a Time-Scheduled EC2 Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2

I have a scraper script, using Selenium that I am wanting to run once an hour on AWS. Because of this script using Selenium, it can't just run in a simple Lambda function, so I must run it in EC2.

I know that you can have an EC2 instance run via the Scheduler but I absolutely cannot get this to work.

I have pulled this off once before on GCP and again on DigitalOcean with complete. I am having issues doing this on AWS.

I am aware that AWS is a very powerful computing service; and I knew that there was supposed to be a learning curve, but I absolutely CANNOT find any documentation on getting this working. I keeping getting redirected to a million things and so many of their own videos are outdated and I feel like there is such a web of loops just to get a simple script to run hourly.

Can someone point me to a place with a basic step-by-step to set up an EC2 to run once per hour?

Comment: You didn't provide the details of your solution and what exactly is the problem, could you please edit the question so it can be answerable?

Comment: There are tons of documentation on AWS with tutorials of all kinds. You should really explain, what your difficulty is, otherwise noone will be able to help you.

Comment: Here's how I'd do it: Cron expression configured as [AWS CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) with [AWS Batch Job as target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch-cwe-target.html).

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more information. For example, do you wish to keep the Amazon EC2 instance running continuously and simply trigger a program on the instance, or do you want to start the instance on a regular schedule and then turn itself off when the job is complete? See also: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)